# CLT convergence rate for sum of uniforms (in TV distance)

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, asymptotics

Suppose $X_1, \cdots, X_n \sim_{\mathrm{iid}} U([-1,1])$, where $U([-1, 1])$ denotes the continuous uniform distribution over the interval $[-1, 1]$ (so $E[X_i] = 0$ and $\text{Var}[X_i]= 1/3$). Let $D_n$ denote the distribution of the following sum, scaled to have unit variance:
$$ \sqrt{\frac{3}{n}} \sum_{i = 1}^n X_i \sim D_n.$$
Note that $D_n$ is a scaled and shifted version of the [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). Is it known how quickly $D_n$ converges to $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ (i.e. the standard normal distribution) in total variation (TV) distance? Some quick experimentation for small values of $n$ in Mathematica possibly indicates
$$ \Delta_{\mathrm{TV}}\left(D_n, \mathcal{N}(0, 1) \right)\stackrel{?}{\le} O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right), $$
but I couldn't find a simple way to try to prove it. The closest thing I could find is the [Berry–Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem), but that only gives a bound on the the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_statistic) (i.e. max difference in CDFs), which does not generally imply a TV distance bound.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks so much!

---

EDIT: [Only keep reading if you want to see the empirical results for small $n$.]

Below are the empirical values for $ \Delta_{\mathrm{TV}}\left(D_n, \mathcal{N}(0, 1) \right)$ (computed in Mathematica by `N[1/2*Integrate[Abs[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x] - Sqrt[n/3]*PDF[UniformSumDistribution[n, {-1, 1}], x*Sqrt[n/3]]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]]` for varying values of $n$):

| $n$ | $\Delta_{\mathrm{TV}}$ |
| --- | --- |
| $1$ | $0.1976779590175315$ |
| $2$ | $0.05124700117544534$ |
| $3$ | $0.027101879212265846$ |
| $4$ | $0.019292677385873307$ |
| $5$ | $0.014897694156660687$ |
| $6$ | $0.012364908454190667$ |
| $7$ | $0.010492076525242137$ |
| $8$ | $0.009125408176875193$ |
| $9$ | $0.008072492963113527$ |
| $10$ | $0.007237608640375671$ |
| $11$ | $0.00655926922222608$ |
| $12$ | $0.005997229294516531$ |
| $13$ | $0.0055239287588410195$ |
| $14$ | $0.005119885056770444$ |
| $15$ | $0.00477093097015108$ |

Computing a linear regression on top of the log-log version of the table for $5 \leq n \leq 15$ gives $\ln(\Delta_{\mathrm{TV}}) \approx -2.53629 - 1.03812 \ln(n)$ with $R^2 \ge 0.9999$. For this reason (i.e. because $- 1.03812 < -1$ and $R^2$ is very close to $1$), it seemed like $\Delta_{\mathrm{TV}} \le O\left( \frac{1}{n} \right)$ is empirically possible.

Comment: If the pdf of $D_n$ is greater than the standard normal pdf in $k$ connected regions, then the total variation distance is at most $2k$ times the K-S distance. So graphing those $k$ regions (and computing $k$) for a few different $n$ might help solve the problem quickly. For example: Is $k\le 3$ for all $n$?

Comment: (i) Berry-Esseen type bounds in relative entropy, and hence TV (by Pinsker's inequality), are thoroughly discussed in the following PTRF paper https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00440-013-0510-3.pdf. (ii) Are you sure about the empirically observed $O(1/n)$ rate?  Can you please share some of these empirical results in your post?  In particular, this seems to defy the usual Monte Carlo error $O(1/\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the reference! Indeed, it looks like the PTRF paper gives a $O(1/\sqrt{n})$ bound by Theorem 1.1. Thanks for sharing! I just added experimental justification for the possible $O(1/n)$ bound. Is there any hope for (validity or proof) of that?

Comment: Thanks for the Mathematica code snippet!  Here is a slight modification to help "see" the rate: ListLogLogPlot[{Table[
   NIntegrate[
    Abs[PDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x] - 
      Sqrt[n/3]*
       PDF[UniformSumDistribution[n, {-1, 1}], 
        Sqrt[n/3] x]], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}], {n, 1, 15}], 
  Table[0.1/n, {n, 1, 15}]}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee : The TV distance is $\sim c/n$, where $c=0.14\dots$. Please see the answer below.

Comment: @IosifPinelis  Thanks; of course, I already upvoted your answer.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee : Thank you for your appreciation.

Comment: [Here is one answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/error-in-normal-approximation-to-a-uniform-sum-distribution?rq=1) with precise estimates and references that I gave several years ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand\dee{\Delta_{\mathrm{TV}}}\newcommand{\vpi}{\varphi}$Let $f_n$ denote the pdf of
\begin{equation*}
    S_n:=\sqrt{\frac3n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i
\end{equation*}
and let $\vpi$ denote the standard normal pdf. Then
\begin{equation*}
    \dee(D_n,N(0,1))=\int|f_n-\vpi|\le I_{n1}+I_{n2}+I_{n3}, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    I_{n1}:=\int_{|x|\le\sqrt{3n}}|f_n(x)-\vpi(x)|\,dx,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    I_{n2}:=\int_{|x|>\sqrt{3n}}f_n(x)\,dx,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    I_{n3}:=\int_{|x|>\sqrt{3n}}\vpi(x)\,dx. 
\end{equation*}

We bound $I_{n1}$ using the asymptotic expansion in the central limit theorem given (say) by Theorem 7 (with $k=5$ and $l=1$) on p. 175 in the book by [Petrov](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-65809-9). Noting also Lemma 10 on p. 173 and the expressions for $Q_{kn}(x)$ on p. 138 of the same book, as well as the fact that $EX_i=EX_i^3=0$ for all $i$, we see that
\begin{equation*}
    f_n(x)=\vpi(x)\Big(1+\frac{P_2(x)}n\Big)+O\Big(\frac1{n^{3/2}}\Big) 
\end{equation*}
uniformly in all real $x$, where $P_2$ is a certain polynomial. It follows that $I_{n1}=O(1/n)$. Also, $I_{n2}=0$, since $|S_n|\le\sqrt{\frac3n}\,n=\sqrt{3n}$. Finally, it is easy to see that $I_{n3}=o(1/n)$.

Thus, by \eqref{1},
\begin{equation*}
    \dee(D_n,N(0,1))=O(1/n), \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{equation*}
as desired.

---

In fact, $P_2(x)=\frac1{20}(3-6x^2+x^4)$, and hence, slightly modifying the above reasoning,  we see that
\begin{equation*}
    \dee(D_n,N(0,1))\sim\frac cn, 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation}
    c:=\int\vpi|P_2|=
    \frac{e^{-3/2-\sqrt{3/2}}}{5\sqrt\pi}  
    \Big(e^{\sqrt{6}} \sqrt{9-3\sqrt{6}}+\sqrt{9+3\sqrt{6}}\,\Big) \\ 
   =0.140030\ldots. 
\end{equation}

Here is the graph $\big\{\big(n,\frac nc\,\dee(D_n,N(0,1))\big)\colon n\in\{3,\dots,15\}\big\}$:

[image]

---

Following the lines of the proof, it easy to see that \eqref{2} will hold whenever, say, the $X_i$'s are iid with $EX_i=EX_i^3=0$ and light enough distribution tails (in your case, the $X_i$'s are iid symmetric random variables with no distribution tails), provided that there is some natural $k$ such that $S_k$ has an absolutely continuous pdf with integrable derivative (in your case, $k=2$ will do).

Comment: (+1) Uspensky (1937) provides a similar result, in flavor, based on a straightforward analysis of characteristic functions, as detailed in [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30468/error-in-normal-approximation-to-a-uniform-sum-distribution?rq=1). Empirically, the bound seems reasonably tight.

Comment: @cardinal : Thank you for your comment. I actually own the Uspensky book, but had not noticed that result (which is for the Kolmogorov distance, though).